# Android emulator unfortunately HelloFacebookSample has stopped

Tags: java, android, facebook, emulation

I am a new to android APP. I download facebook sdk for android (https://developers.facebook.com/android/). Everything is fine except running in emulator. Everything samples in SDK cannot rightly be ran and a error of "unfortualtely, XXX has stopped" is popped. Could someone meet similar problems? Thanks.
Here is the log in LogCat:

```
06-02 16:33:41.165: D/dalvikvm(536): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-02 16:33:41.425: I/dalvikvm(536): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
06-02 16:33:41.715: W/dalvikvm(536): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity; (59)
06-02 16:33:41.715: W/dalvikvm(536): Link of class 'Lcom/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity;' failed
06-02 16:33:41.715: D/AndroidRuntime(536): Shutting down VM
06-02 16:33:41.715: W/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook/com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-02 16:33:41.755: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  ... 11 more
06-02 16:33:42.365: I/dalvikvm(536): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-02 16:33:42.375: I/dalvikvm(536): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-02 16:33:42.875: I/dalvikvm(536): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-02 16:33:42.885: I/dalvikvm(536): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >
        <activity android:name=".HelloFacebookSampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the source code:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2012 Facebook
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphPlace;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.*;

import java.util.*;

public class HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final Location SEATTLE_LOCATION = new Location("") {
        {
            setLatitude(47.6097);
            setLongitude(-122.3331);
        }
    };

    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook:PendingAction";

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private Button pickFriendsButton;
    private Button pickPlaceButton;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
    private GraphUser user;

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be populated in order to post a
                // status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        });

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostPhoto();
            }
        });

        pickFriendsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickFriendsButton);
        pickFriendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPickFriends();
            }
        });

        pickPlaceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickPlaceButton);
        pickPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPickPlace();
            }
        });

        controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_ui_container);

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment != null) {
            // If we're being re-created and have a fragment, we need to a) hide the main UI controls and
            // b) hook up its listeners again.
            controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (fragment instanceof FriendPickerFragment) {
                setFriendPickerListeners((FriendPickerFragment) fragment);
            } else if (fragment instanceof PlacePickerFragment) {
                setPlacePickerListeners((PlacePickerFragment) fragment);
            }
        }

        // Listen for changes in the back stack so we know if a fragment got popped off because the user
        // clicked the back button.
        fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    // We need to re-show our UI.
                    controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
                (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        pickFriendsButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        pickPlaceButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);

        if (enableButtons && user != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, user.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
        String getId();
    }

    private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = getString(R.string.success);
            String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, message, id);
        } else {
            title = getString(R.string.error);
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE);
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO);
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    private void showPickerFragment(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
        fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment, FacebookException error) {
                showAlert(getString(R.string.error), error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // We want the fragment fully created so we can use it immediately.
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        fragment.loadData(false);
    }

    private void onClickPickFriends() {
        final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

        setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setFriendPickerListeners(final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String results = "";

        Collection<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
        if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                names.add(user.getName());
            }
            results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
        } else {
            results = getString(R.string.no_friends_selected);
        }

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), results);
    }

    private void onPlacePickerDone(PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String result = "";

        GraphPlace selection = fragment.getSelection();
        if (selection != null) {
            result = selection.getName();
        } else {
            result = getString(R.string.no_place_selected);
        }

        showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), result);
    }

    private void onClickPickPlace() {
        final PlacePickerFragment fragment = new PlacePickerFragment();
        fragment.setLocation(SEATTLE_LOCATION);
        fragment.setTitleText(getString(R.string.pick_seattle_place));

        setPlacePickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setPlacePickerListeners(final PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
        fragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                if (fragment.getSelection() != null) {
                    onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
            } else {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your manifest please?

Comment: check whether your activity is registered in manifest

Comment: I showed my manifest just above. I tried v3.0.1 and v3.0 and both have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From logcat

```
06-02 16:33:41.715: W/dalvikvm(536): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity; (59)
06-02 16:33:41.715: W/dalvikvm(536): Link of class 'Lcom/facebook/samples/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity;' failed
```

You need to move external .jar files to 'libs' folder otherwise their classes won't be included in the .dex file created.

This issues happens starting ADT 17. To resolve, make sure ADT is correct, build path is correctly configured and external jar files are in libs folder.

Comment: Thanks. But I moved android-support-v4.jar to local libs folder and added it to the project. The problem cannot be fixed.

Comment: Did you clean rebuild the project. From my understanding, your activity HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends Fragments.

Comment: Yes, I cleaned and rebuilt. The HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity. I pasted my code too.

Comment: As per my understanding, this occurs due to build path issue. I would suggest you to search for this error on stackOverflow and try applying suggested solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Anirudh. You are right. Finally I find the problems is similar like http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362. It is a bug from the ADT.

Comment: Hi, @Anirudh.  Sorry for that. 'Cause I have not enough reputation to upvote. I Just accepted the answer. But it is not the exact solution. Actually I adopted http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362. Could you please change your answer please? Just avoid to confuse others. Thanks.